# error while deploying a contract Error:invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5

Tags: solidity, remix

```
contract Test
{

   uint public x=21;
   uint age=10;
   
   // constructor()
   // {
   //    x=0;
   // }

   constructor(uint new_x)
   {
      x=new_x;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, given the error, the problem isn't in the solidity file but in the way you deployed the contract. Make sure to not leave empty the value of `new_x` when you're deploying (in Remix, it's in the box right of the "Deploy" button)

Answer (score 0):

`contract.deploy(BigInt(new_x))` should cover your issue.